# How can I find the Windows Device Exchange ActiveSync ID?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, activesync

When reviewing Activesync connection attempts for one user, I can see one connection initiating from a WindowsMail device, which seems to be a Windows machine with Windows Mail app.

How can I identify what is this machine as I only have the ExchangeID of it? 
Is it possible to get the exchange ID of Windows Machines?

Note that it is only shown for one user.

Comment: What is the ExchangeID that you mentioned? This is what I got when I view mobile device details. There is only Device ID. Are you intending to get the ExhcangeID from the windows machine?
[device details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S50ZR.png)

Comment: I think it is the same DeviceID you are referring to. In Exchange 2010, when I run the below command it shows the devices connected:Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox:“[User]” | fl         You can see the DeviceID for the devices connected. But how can I know the deviceID of Windows machines from the device itself? I need it to confirm which is the device connected.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=D_T4ags1Gyw
Watch the video above, follow the steps to get your windows device id.